# Is it safe to return a new Collection in Hibernate entity class getters?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am wondering if it is safe to return a new instance of a Collection (i.e. ArrayList) in the getter method for a Hibernate entity containing the previously set entities.
The reason I think it would not be safe is beacause if Hibernate relies on the Collections modifying methods such as add, remove, and clear to modify which entities are to be persisted, then I certainly cannot return a new Collection as any modification to the collection would not be persisted to the database. If however, Hibernate uses the setter method for the collection, and simply sets a new collection each time it needs to modify the persisted collection's state, then I think I should be fine.

Take a look at this code example which roughly illustrates my case:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "my_entity_id", unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    // other attributes...

    @Transient
    private List<OtherEntityWrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "my_entity", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<OtherEntity> getOtherEntities() {
        // A new List is returned containing the previously set entities
        return wrappers.stream().map((e) -> e.getOtherEntity()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void setOtherEntities(List<OtherEntity> otherEntities) {
        // transient wrappers collection is cleared and reset with the otherEntities List
        wrappers.clear();
        for (OtherEntity otherEntity : otherEntities) {
            wrappers.add(new OtherEntityWrapper(otherEntity));
        }
    }

// For internal use
public List<OtherEntityWrapper> getWrappers() {
    return wrappers;
}

}
```

What I am doing is using the hibernate entity (OtherEntity) in the OtherEntityWrapper class which handles a lot of the business logic, and is really an extension of the properties defined in the OtherEntity class which are used internaly. There should only be one OtherEntityWrapper class for each persisted OtherEntity. So since the OtherEntityWrapper class cannot be the entity itself, it acts as a decorator of the OtherEntity class.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: it turns out that you cannot use both property accessor annotations and field annotations. Hibernate will choose the access method based on where the @Id annotation is, so in this example, it would be on the property accessor

Edit 2: I also found out that you cannot return a new Collection if it is annotated to have the delete-orphan feature (which I forgot about), because Hibernate needs to know when you use the collections modifying methods so that it can cascade the removal action and remove the entity from the database (for convenience). However, if I remove the orphanRemoveal attribute, my question still stands.

Comment: I've used this approach(return a new collection) in JPA with EclipseLink and it worked as expected.

Comment: What if you use a dumb list to annotate it so hibernate knows about that collection: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "my_entity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities;` The getters and setters stay untouched, only removing the annotation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on add, remove and clear method, then you can set a new collection every time to modify. The effect is same. 
Actually hibernate does not rely on add, remove and clear method. It simply correlate elements that is in the List at transaction commit. If you change the list, modify or replace with new list, that's not any matter. Hibernate only updates database at transaction commit time. It only sees the elements of the list at that time and update the database accordingly.